# How do I vertically align a node with the center of a cluster?

Tags: graphviz, diagrammer

I am looking for a way to align individual nodes in graphviz with an entire subgraph/cluster.

I am currently teaching a small team of analysts to use `rmarkdown` and I want to allow them to include simple graphs and flowcharts in their documents. I therefore use `DiagrammeR` (and `viz.js`) to render charts written in `dot`. To increase user adoption, I want to minimize complexity and avoid `HTML` and use *raw* `dot`.

Our problem is that we frequently try to align **nodes** with **subgraphs/clusters** containing multiple nodes, but we cannot align the entire subgraph with the node. Alignment only works with the constituent nodes within the subgraph/cluster. (see nodes **C,D,E** and **G,T** below)

I have tried to create a record node using `GT [shape = record label="{G | T}"]` but that does not allow individual styling of the two nodes.

I have also tried creating an HTML record node which allows individual styling but increases complexity too much and requires users to know HTML.

Finally, I have tried to insert an invisible node inside the clusters to "simulate" the center and then use the invisible node for alignment. This unfortunately pushes  **G** and **T** to far apart and doesn't achieve the intended effect.

```
digraph G {

  graph [splines = false, ranksep = 0.2]
  edge [style = "invis"]
  node [shape = box, width = 7.5]
  A B H 

  node [shape = circle, width = 1.5]

  subgraph cluster_2 {
    rank = same 
    C D E
  }

  subgraph cluster_1 { 
    G [shape = box]
    T [shape = box]
  }
  A -> B
  G -> T
  B -> {C D E G}
  {C D E T} -> H 

}
```

The following gives the output:

[image]

In the picture above, the subgraph containing **G** and **T** is not aligned with the subgraph containing **C,D,E**.

Is there a way to vertically align the centers of the two subgraphs?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that GraphViz only align node rows and {C D E} is one row where as {G->T} is two rows so {C D E} can only be align with either G or T

You can however align {C D E} with the space between G and T though that is probably not what you want. E.g. like this:

```
digraph G {

  graph [splines = false, ranksep = 0.2]
  //edge [style = "invis"]
  node [shape = box, width = 7.5]
  A B H 

  node [shape = circle, width = 1.5]

  subgraph cluster_2 {
    rank = same 
    C D E
  }

  subgraph cluster_1 { 
    G [shape = box]
    T [shape = box]
  }
  A -> B
  G -> T[minlen=2]
  B -> G
  B -> {C D E} -> H [minlen=2]
    T -> H
}
```

Resulting in:

[image]